# Split SQL Select Statement with RegEx

Tags: java, regex

I want to find the whole list of columns in the an SQL Select statement with Regex.

For example,

```
Select col1, col2,col3 from tab1;
```

Required

```
[1]: col1
[2]: col2
[3]: col3
```

One way is this regex

```
select.*from;
```

and then split the string. Is there any other more efficient method?

Thanks

Comment: A regex will only work for the most simple SQL statements. What about column alias? What about sub-queries or sub-selects inside the select list?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that your version is the most efficient way.

You *could* construct a regex that grabs all those in a single run, but it's surely not going to be as fast as what you're doing, and it only looks ahead to see a `from` following, not behind whether there's a `select` behind it:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\w+(?=\\s*(?:,|\\bfrom\\b))(?=.*\\bfrom\\b)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
}
```

So all in all, I'd say go with what you have. Maybe make the asterisk lazy:

```
select.*?from
```